# WebGrid rendered inside partial view will raise "“jQuery is not defined”" , when trying to do ajax-based paging or filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, partial-views, webgrid

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application. and i have the following:-
1. main view which contain @`Html.Action`, that calls an action method which return partial view.
2. inside the partial view, i define a web grid.
3.if i click on a link such as "Show Details" link inside the partial view's webgrid, a modal popup will show and inside the modal popup i will have another web grid.
The problem i am facing is that if i try to do Ajax-based sorting or paging inside the web-grid that is rendered inside the modal popup i will get the followig error :-

```
"jQuery is not defined".
```

The main view is as follow:-

```
@Html.Action("GetStaffSkill", "Staff", new  {staffmasterdetails = Model.SkillID})
```

and the above @Html.Action will call the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult GetStaffSkill(.....)
  {


      var records = new PagedList<Staff>();
    //codegoes here
      return PartialView("_gridstaff",records);
  }
```

and the partial view ,which have the "Show detials" link is :-

@model SkillManagement.Models.PagedList

```
              <div class="well">


    <div style="margin-top:17px;">
        @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(
                    canPage: true,
                    rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                    canSort: true,
                    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", fieldNamePrefix: "staff");

        grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

        @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
        fillEmptyRows: false,
        tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        columns: grid.Columns(

          grid.Column("Skill",canSort:false,format:

             @<text>


<a data-modal='' href="@Url.Action("ShowDetails", "Skill", new {skillmasterDetail= item.StaffID, skillsummaryView=true })   "   title='show detials'>  
Show Details</a>
```

finally the Script that is responsible to show modal popup:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        //$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e){
            $('#myModalContent').css({ "max-height": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    //height: 1000,
                    //width: 1200,
                    //resizable: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    draggable: true
                }, 'show').draggable({
                    handle: ".modal-header"
                });
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
                bindForm(this);
              $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
                  var target = $(this);
                    target.autocomplete({
                        source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000, appendTo: $("#myModal")



                   });

                });
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
```

so can anyone adivce how i can force jQuery to stay live and understand the partial view that is rendered from the @Html.Action ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page code is executed from top to bottom. Your JQuery `Scripts.Render` are probably in the foot of your layout.

To solve this you can move it to the top of your layout cshtml page.

But i dont know if this is the better solution because render scripts in the foot of page prevent delaying page display.